# phpMyAdmin allow remote users

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I need to modify the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`
in order to allow remote users (not only localhost) to login

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you want it open to everyone or just specific ip addresses?

Comment: I want to open it for everyone

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Euloiix no because the virtual machine where PHPmyAdmin was running is no longer available

Answer (score 85):

The other answers so far seem to advocate the complete replacement of the <Directory/> block, this is not needed and may remove extra settings like the 'AddDefaultCharset UTF-8' now included.

#### Update 2021

The config file is now simplified so just needs a single line adding:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   Require local
   # ADD following line:
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

#### Original Answer

To allow remote access you need to add 1 line to the 2.4 config block or change 2 lines in the 2.2 (depending on your apache version):

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       # ADD following line:
       Require all granted
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     # CHANGE following 2 lines:
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Centos 7. Thanks.

Comment: Works on EC2 instances.

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me, that did. Thanks Chris!!

Comment: EVERYONE: Try this first, it is the only one that I found works on EC2 linux instance. Thank you chris!

Comment: This worked for me also with Centos 7, VPS.

Answer (score 21):

use this,it got fixed for me, over centOS 7

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Works on my amazon linux

Answer (score 4):

Replace the contents of the first `<directory>` tag.

Remove:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
 <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  # Apache 2.4
  <RequireAny>
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require ip ::1
  </RequireAny>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  # Apache 2.2
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And place this instead:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache afterwards.

Comment: mag 16 23:33:29 localhost.localdomain httpd[2212]: httpd: Syntax error on line 353 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf: /etc/httpd
mag 16 23:33:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mag 16 23:33:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

Comment: In browser I obtain: `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.`

Comment: I add a note to my previous comment, since it is not possible to edit it. I have not neither been prompted for user and password, before getting the `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.` error message

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Replace

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.4
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 127.0.0.1
            Require ip ::1
        </RequireAny>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.2
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from ::1
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

With this:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Add the following line for ease of access:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: In browser I obtain: `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.`

Comment: I add a note to my previous comment, since it is not possible to edit it. I have not neither been prompted for user and password, before getting the `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.` error message

Comment: It should prompt for username and password with a phpMyAdmin Login screen. Did you try to restart Apache?

Comment: Yes I restarted Apache

Answer (score 3):

My setup was a little different using XAMPP. in httpd-xampp.conf I had to make the following change.

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

change to

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    #makes it so I can config the database from anywhere
    #change the line below
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

I need to state that I'm brand new at this so I'm just hacking around but this is how I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment all lines in first Directory. Or you can remove these lines, but better to keep in case later you want to add some restrictions, you will uncomment.

```
#<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
#     # Apache 2.4
#     <RequireAny>
#       Require ip 127.0.0.1
#       Require ip ::1
#     </RequireAny>
#   </IfModule>
#   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
#     # Apache 2.2
#     Order Deny,Allow
#     Deny from All
#     Allow from 127.0.0.1
#     Allow from ::1
#   </IfModule>
#</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on getting a 403 error although I had all of the Apache settings mentioned in the other answers correct.

It was a fresh Centos 7 server and it turned out that the issue was not the Apache  settings but the fact that the PhpMyAdmin did not serve at all. The solution was to install php and add the php directive to apache.conf:

- sudo yum install php php-mysql
- vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  add something like
- DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm 
  to serve php index files also
  and then restart apache

Don't forget to restart Apache server to take effect
 - systemctl restart httpd.service

I hope this helps. I first thought my issue was Apache directives, so I post my solution here.